# Joining objects

Tags: modifiers, objects

I would like to join two objects, one is a cilinder with modifier "Curve", so it's sort of bended. I would like to attach a UV sphere (which shape I changed a bit in sculpting regime) to it but as I do so, it messes up with the modifier. Is there a way to join these two objects and keeping their shape? Thanks

Comment: Yous could use the boolean modifier set to ***union***.

Answer (score 4):

When you join the two objects together, their base meshes without modifiers are combined, then the modifiers act on the joined mesh. You need to apply the *Curve* modifier first. Before doing so, it is recommended that you duplicate the object(s) to keep a backup in case something goes wrong further down the line.